# Encountered errors while bringing up the project+Docker compose

Tags: mongodb, docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I used SpringBoot RestApi Microservices and MongoDB.
In MongoDB, I have three Databases such as player-db, game-db and score-db.
My services are in the different folders and for each one I defined Dockerfile.
Dockerfile for player service:

```
    FROM openjdk:8
COPY ./target/demo-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar player.jar
EXPOSE 8080
ENTRYPOINT ["java","-Dspring.data.mongodb.uri=mongodb://db:27017/","-jar","-Djava.rmi.server.hostname=0.0.0.0", "player.jar"]
```

Dockerfile for game service:

```
    FROM openjdk:8
COPY ./target/demo-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar game.jar
EXPOSE 8080
ENTRYPOINT ["java","-Dspring.data.mongodb.uri=mongodb://db1:27017/","-jar","-Djava.rmi.server.hostname=0.0.0.0", "game.jar"]
```

and Dockerfile for score service:

```
 FROM openjdk:8
COPY ./target/demo-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar score.jar
EXPOSE 8080
ENTRYPOINT ["java","-Dspring.data.mongodb.uri=mongodb://db2:27017/","-jar","-Djava.rmi.server.hostname=0.0.0.0", "score.jar"]
```

And I defined a docker-compose.yml file:

```
    version: "3"
services:
    player-docker:
        build:
            context: ./
            dockerfile: ./src/main/java/spring/multiple/mongo/project/player/DockerFile
        restart: always
        ports:
            - 8080:8080
        depends_on:
            - db
    game-docker:
        build:
            context: ./
            dockerfile: ./src/main/java/spring/multiple/mongo/project/game/DockerFile
        restart: always
        ports:
            - 8080:8080
        depends_on:
            - db1
    score-docker:
        build:
            context: ./
            dockerfile: ./src/main/java/spring/multiple/mongo/project/score/Dockerfile
        restart: always
        ports:
            - 8080:8080
        depends_on:
            - db2 
    db:
        image: mongo
        volumes:
            - mongodata:/data/db
        ports:
            - 27017:27017
        restart: always
        environment:
            MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_DATABASE: player-db
    db1:
        image: mongo
        volumes:
            - mongodata:/data/db1
        ports:
            - 27017:27017
        restart: always
        environment:
            MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_DATABASE: game-db
    db2:
        image: mongo
        volumes:
            - mongodata:/data/db2
        ports:
            - 27017:27017
        restart: always
        environment:
            MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_DATABASE: score-db
volumes:
    mongodata:
```

In fact, in docker-compose file I tried to define different databases for my services, but when I execute docker-compose up I get an error
[image: Docker]

The ERROR:

```
    $ docker-compose up
Starting springmultiplemongoproject_db_1 ...
Starting springmultiplemongoproject_db2_1 ... error
Creating springmultiplemongoproject_db1_1 ...

ERROR: for springmultiplemongoproject_db2_1  Cannot start service db2: driver fa
iled programming external connectivity on endpoint springmultiplemongoproject_db
2_1 (736a5c8f4a485472d7d5c622f29fd892b533794b352cbccc97dae5c54e3ae54f): Bind for
Creating springmultiplemongoproject_db1_1 ... error

ERROR: for springmultiplemongoproject_db1_1  Cannot start service db1: driver fa
Starting springmultiplemongoproject_db_1  ... done
1_1 (e0ea7a6e31f0bec010ccfef67705732904d3fcf0eee55cee8577d464583070ff): Bind for
 0.0.0.0:27017 failed: port is already allocated
Creating springmultiplemongoproject_player-docker_1 ... done

ERROR: for db2  Cannot start service db2: driver failed programming external con
nectivity on endpoint springmultiplemongoproject_db2_1 (736a5c8f4a485472d7d5c622
f29fd892b533794b352cbccc97dae5c54e3ae54f): Bind for 0.0.0.0:27017 failed: port i
s already allocated

ERROR: for db1  Cannot start service db1: driver failed programming external con
nectivity on endpoint springmultiplemongoproject_db1_1 (e0ea7a6e31f0bec010ccfef6
7705732904d3fcf0eee55cee8577d464583070ff): Bind for 0.0.0.0:27017 failed: port i
s already allocated
ERROR: Encountered errors while bringing up the project.
```

I am beginner in Docker, and I read many documents, but I could not find any solution.

Comment: can you put your error as text, not as screenshot!

Comment: remove `"27017:27017"` double quotes around from port numbers, and clean your images. sometimes the docker build an image from previous image cache if previous image build was not pefect then issue come.

Comment: try this command,  `docker rm images $(docker images -q)`

Comment: @DupinderSingh I did all that you told, but nothing changed and I have the same error

Comment: try to run this command `docker-compose -f "docker-compose.yml" up -d --build` in detached mode and with build tag

Comment: Why are you binding every database services to the same port? Also your application services. The ports will clash you have to specify different ports like 8080:8080, 8081:8080, 8082:8080

Comment: @thammada every container is isolated inside docker and port numbers are free to be same. docker-compose assign one IP address to a container to differentiate. To access docker container through IP address user `https://dockercontainername:<portNumber>`

Comment: The internal container ports are free to be the same, but If you want to bind it to the host `mongodb://localhost:hostPort`, they have to be different, how else should we address different services from the host?

Comment: correct me if I am wrong, but like this `mongodb://db:27017`

Comment: That's how you access it from other containers, but what if you want to access from the host? You can also specify just `8080` instead of `8080:8080` (without colons). If you want to let docker compose choose a host port for you. In that case, you can put `8080` for all your application services and `27017` for al your database services

Comment: @thammada ya I got it what you are saying, it okay to be the same port number for docker container, but should be different for host machine. Thankyou I was just confussed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are binding the same host ports to different docker services. You have to specify different host ports for each service. The syntax for specifying ports is as follows:

```yaml
 ports:
   - "HOST:CONTAINER"
```

So for the `HOST` part you need different port numbers

```
version: "3"
services:
    player-docker:
...
        ports:
            - 8081:8080
    game-docker:
...
        ports:
            - 8082:8080
    score-docker:
...
        ports:
            - 8083:8080
    db:
...
        ports:
            - 27018:27017
    db1:
...
        ports:
            - 27019:27017
    db2:
...
        ports:
            - 27019:27017
...
```

Or if you want docker compose to assign host port numbers for you, you can omit the HOST part, like this

```
version: "3"
services:
    player-docker:
...
        ports:
            - 8080
    game-docker:
...
        ports:
            - 8080
    score-docker:
...
        ports:
            - 8080
    db:
...
        ports:
            - 27017
    db1:
...
        ports:
            - 27017
    db2:
...
        ports:
            - 27017
...
```

Or if you don't want to bind ports to the host for the database services, you can just omit the `ports` part

Comment: Thank you. it is correct, and it works. just one thing, when I used this suggestion in Postman I getting Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:8080.

Comment: I used the mashin IP such as 192.168.99.100:8080/player and after that i getting "status": 500,
    "error": "Internal Server Error". I checked docker-shell when I executed docker-compose up

Comment: and I saw this: game-docker_1    |      at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [na:1.8.0_252]
game-docker_1    | Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Con
nection refused). could you help me please

Comment: Could you pot your current docker-compose file along with the errors in a new question?

Answer (score 3):

This image might help you to understand why we have to write a different port for the host machine.

The container is an OS in itself. But the container is connecting to the outside OS which is hosting multiple containers. So to help host machine to identify which container you are talking to, we need to use a different port number

[image]